# mvc email with controller action as attachment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, smtpclient

is it possible to pass a controller action as path on smtp email?

I have this method in my controller which gets me what i searched for:

```
 public void ConnectToDatabase(Modelclass uc)
    {
       // IList<Modelclass> list = new List<Modelclass>();
        var query = (from a in db.DBTable
                     where a.IDNumber.Equals(uc.ID_Number)
                    select a).ToList();
        var tt = query;
    }
```

and i call this method on this action on the same controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetUserInput(ModelClass model )
    {

        var idnumber = model.ID_Number;
        var startdate = model.Start_Date;
        var enddate = model.End_Date;

        ConnectToDatabase(model);
        // validate your date here and return True if validated
        if (model.End_Date < model.Start_Date)
        {
            return Json(false);

        }
        return View("Search"); 

    }
```

so i want to pass this "connectToDatabase" method as an attachment to the email il be sending.

where do i even start?

Comment: Hi @fulufhelo, I would like to ask do you pass `ConnectToDatabase` or `GetUserInput` into email?

Comment: I want to pass ConnectToDatabase @ShawnYan

Comment: AFAIK you cannot pass method into email. You can pass `Url.Action` that will get called when the user click the link.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you wanted but you can write a Url.Action to your stmp email like this.

```
var callbackUrl = Url.Action("Action", "Controller",
                    new
                    {
                        Idnumber = model.ID_Number;
                        Startdate = model.Start_Date;
                        Enddate = model.End_Date;
                    }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
```

Then assign the url into your email

```
message.Body =String.Format("<b><i>Click the following link to view attachment</i></b> <a href =\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
```

After that write your controller with the same matching parameters with Url.Action

```
public void ConnectToDatabase(string IdNumber, DateTime Startdate, DateTime Enddate)
{
    //do something here...
}
```

Comment: Hello @Shawn its not attaching the results coming from the database

Comment: actually when i get the email it has the link to the attachment but it gives me the 404 error when i click the link.

Comment: Ok, is your attachment some kind of Excel file, or just a link?

Comment: I changed the ConnectToDatabase method to an ActionResult that returns a Json file, It is getting the values now but just display these brackets "[ ]" instead of the real information